# skew and animate image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to skew and animate image on a canvas. I can draw Image on canvas but how to skew and animate it after drawing? How to get reference of the image which is drawn on canvas?

I can draw image on canvas like this

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "to get reference" regarding canvas. Canvas is just pixels, every discrete object you want to handle, will have to be handled by your code painting on the canvas.

Comment: so if I have 3,4 images on canvas. I have to redraw everything to animate?

Comment: Correct. For animation you have to know every bit of information and redraw on every frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very rough sketch to get you started:

```
$(function () {
  var
    loaded = false,
    ctx = $('canvas')[0].getContext('2d'),
    img;

  img = $('<img>', {
    src: 'http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e25f40f6711403073e7da6c33be21eb8?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG'
  }).on('load', function () {
    loaded = true;
  }).get(0);


  setInterval(function () {
    var f = 0;

    return function () {
      if (loaded) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

        ctx.save();
        ctx.setTransform (1, f, 0, 1, 0, 0);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 50, 50);
        ctx.restore();

        f += 0.01;

        if (f > 1) {
          f = 0;
        }
      }
    };
  }(), 16);
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UHSKL/